# kernel crash with kmalloc

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kmalloc

I am trying to assign memory using `kmalloc` in kernel code in fact in a queueing discipline. I want to assign memory to `q->agg_queue_hdr` of which `q` is a queueing discipline and `agg_queue_hdr` is a struct, so if assign memory like this:

```
q->agg_queue_hdr=kmalloc(sizeof(struct agg_queue), GFP_ATOMIC);
```

the kernel crashes. Based on the examples of `kmalloc` I saw from searching, I now changed it to:

```
agg_queue_hdr=kmalloc(sizeof(struct agg_queue), GFP_ATOMIC);
```

with which the kernel doesn't crash. Now I want to know how can I assign memory to the pointer `q->agg_queue_hdr`?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `q` is pointed to a valid area of memory.  Then you should be able to assign `q->agg_queue_hdr` like you had it to begin with.

Comment: Hello thank you for replying,i want to know how can I check if q is pointed to a valid memory? q is a struct defined as follows:  struct aggregate_sched_data *q = qdisc_priv(sch);

Comment: There really is no way of checking q (or any pointer) to know if it's pointed to valid memory.  Typically what I do is initialize my pointers to 0 when I declare them.  Later when I check them, if they're still 0, some memory needs to be allocated for them before I use them.  Then later when I free them, set them back to 0 afterward.

Comment: Sir I really tried to check my pointers if are valid but i seemed not to get it right. Can you please check the sample of my code and help me to do it the right way                                                                        static int aggregate_enqueue(struct sk_buff *skb, struct Qdisc *sch)
{                                                                        if(q->agg_queue_hdr == NULL) //Nothing in the list!                                                                        q->agg_queue_hdr = kmalloc(sizeof(struct agg_queue),GFP_ATOMIC);

Comment: and then the struct of q is as as follows                                                               <code> struct aggregate_sched_data *q = qdisc_priv(sch); // this struct is defined as follows <code>                                                               <code>     struct aggregate_sched_data
   {
 struct qdisc_watchdog watchdog;
         unsigned int        agg_min_size; 
 unsigned int  agg_max_size;
 unsigned int  agg_max_timeout;
 struct agg_queue *agg_queue_hdr;
      
};<code>

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you modify your code with below way, which would avoid kernel panic.

```
if (q->agg_queue_hdr) {
    q->agg_queue_hdr = kmalloc(sizeof(struct agg_queue), GFP_ATOMIC);
}
else {
    printk("[+] q->agg_queue_hdr invalid \n");

    dump_stack();  // print callstack in the kernel log.
```

}

When disassembing "q->agg_queue_hdr", "ldr" instruction will works where kernel panic occurs.

Comment: It shoud be `if (NULL != q) { ... } else { ... }`